# Recordcount returning too many records

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Hello I have some vba code in a Form in MS Access 2013 and for some reason when I get a record set it reports 30 rows when the database really only has 1 row and I have verified this.

When I do a debug print to see the id's it is just the same record duplicated 30 times.

Below is the code that is ran.

```
Option Compare Database

Dim selectPlacement As QueryDef
Dim rs As Recordset

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Set selectPlacement = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("SelectPlacement")
    Me.AddPlacementForm.Form.Visible = False

    selectPlacement.Parameters!stu = Me.student_id.Value
    selectPlacement.Parameters!sem = Me.semester_id.Value
    Me.AddPlacementForm.Form!lstStudent.Value = Me.student_id
    Me.AddPlacementForm.Form!cmbSemester.Value = Me.semester_id
    Me.PlacementsBlock1.Form.Filter = "[semester_id]= '" & Me.semester_id.Value & "'"
    Me.PlacementsBlock2.Form.Filter = "[semester_id]= '" & Me.semester_id.Value & "'"
    Me.PlacementsBlock1.Form.FilterOn = True
    Me.PlacementsBlock2.Form.FilterOn = True

    Set rs = selectPlacement.OpenRecordset
    Call SetUpPlacements(rs)
    rs.Close
    Set selectPlacement = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub SetUpPlacements(rs As Recordset)
    If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
        Me.PlacementsBlock1.Form.Visible = False
        Me.PlacementsBlock2.Form.Visible = False
        Me.AddPlacementForm.Form.Visible = True
    ElseIf rs.RecordCount = 1 Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        If rs!block = 1 Then
            Me.PlacementsBlock1.Form.Visible = False
        Else
            Me.PlacementsBlock2.Form.Visible = False
        End If
        Me.AddPlacementForm.Form.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.PlacementsBlock1.Form.Visible = True
        Me.PlacementsBlock2.Form.Visible = True
        Me.AddPlacementForm.Form.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

And below is the query that is in the query def.

```
SELECT *
FROM student_placements
WHERE (((student_placements.student_id)=[stu]) AND ((student_placements.semester_id)=[sem]));
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the recordset without proper initialization, and thus your call to `rs.RecordCount` does not return the proper value.

You would need to check for an empty recordset via  `If rs.EOF and rs.BOF Then`. To get the proper record count, you will need to call `rs.MoveLast`. Before, the record count is unreliable.

See http://allenbrowne.com/ser-29.html (traps 3 and 4) for more information.